# Add +- 2 SE in regression line R

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I was wondering if it is possible to plot a regression line in R including +- 2* Standard Error.
For example, with `iris` :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Sepal.Width))+geom_smooth(method=lm, color="black")+ theme_bw()
```

the output is:

[image]

How would it possible (if possible) to expand the grey area for values twice the standard error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to manually add the confidence bands via `stat_smooth` and making use of `after_stat`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, color = "black", se = FALSE) +
  stat_smooth(aes(ymin = after_stat(y - 2 * se), ymax = after_stat(y + 2 * se)), geom = "ribbon", method = lm, fill = "grey60", alpha = .4) +
  theme_bw()
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I tried and the plot is identical with the initial one. Only if I change your code into e.g.,  aes(ymin = after_stat(y - 4 * se), ymax = after_stat(y + 4 * se) it increases. Is it possible that by default ggplot() plots 2*SE when se=TRUE?

Comment: Yep. I guess that the default is actually 1.96 (i.e. almost 2) which is the standard way to compute confidence bands.

Comment: @stefan A standard way to compute **two-sided 95%** confidence bands. :) Change either the sidedness or the confidence level and the number changes: if `alpha <- 1-conf.level`, then the specific number to use is `qnorm(1-(alpha/2))` for a two-sided CI.

Comment: Also forgot to mention: +1 :)

Comment: Hi @Alexis. Thx. And of course you are right. Thanks for pointing that out. Always a good idea to remember the basics. (; Best S.